# check whether two objects belongs to same class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++14

How to check whether two objects belong to the same class in std c++ using templates or any function?

```
class A{};
class B{};

int main() 
{
    B b1, b2;
    A a1,a2;
    cout<< issame(a1,b1)<< endl;
    cout<< issame(a1,a2)<< endl;
}
```

Comment: It kinda goes against OOP in general, so despite the fact that it is possible, you might wanna reconsider your design, and re-evaluate the reason why you need to perform this check in the first place.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) function from the standard library help?

Comment: `static_assert( std::is_same< decltype(a1), decltype(b1) >::value );`

Answer (score 0):

C++ is statically typed, `B` and `A` are different types. Maybe its just a matter of your code not demonstrating the use case, but in your code there is no need to "check", you already know that `B` is not `A`. In a template the situation is different, you can have for example:

```
template <typename U, typename V>
void foo(U u, V v);
```

and then `U` and `V` can be either different types or the same. To check if they are the same you can use the type trait [`std::is_same_v<U,V>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)

Answer (score -2):

You can define a function `issame` like

```
#include <type_traits>

//...

template<typename S, typename T>
constexpr bool issame(S, T) {
    return std::is_same<S, T>::value;
}
```

and use it just like in your example.

```
std::cout << issame(a1,b1) << std::endl;  // outputs "0"
std::cout << issame(a1,a2) << std::endl;  // outputs "1"
```

Comment: You're introducing copies for something statically known.